# NoMethodError in UsersController#edit with undefined method `signed_in?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,:password_confirmation)
  end

  def signed_in_user
     unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

code in session helper:

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token

  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))


  self.current_user = user
end


def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

I am using this code,

But I am unable to edit and update my details in the database.

As I am extremely new to this,

Need someone help.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the SessionHelper module in your controller?

From your example code, I'm assuming you're using the **RailsTutorial** by Michael Hartl. You have to include the SessionsHelper in your ApplicationController to be able to use it in all controllers. Check out Listing 8.14 in the book:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery
    include SessionsHelper

    # Force signout to prevent CSRF attacks
    def handle_unverified_request 
        sign_out
        super
    end
end
```

Comment: But, Its showing some error regarding encrypt method and again with signed_in method too....

Comment: I'm sorry, that isn't very useful information to help you further with. Have you worked through the book sequentially and carefully? It's easy to miss an important line when you don't take care. Maybe you should redo the tutorial from the point on where your app lasted worked properly.